# LibreOffice SDK bootstrap

Tags: java, libreoffice

I got the standard jar files + juh-2.4.1.jar and ridl-3.2.1.jar (got errors on import) as referenced libraries in my project. When i get an example piece of code from http://api.libreoffice.org/examples/DevelopersGuide/examples.html#FirstSteps i always land on this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/star/comp/loader/JavaLoader
    at com.sun.star.comp.helper.Bootstrap.createInitialComponentContext(Bootstrap.java:118)
    at com.sun.star.comp.helper.Bootstrap.bootstrap(Bootstrap.java:241)
    at TextDocuments.getRemoteServiceManager(TextDocuments.java:410)
    at TextDocuments.storePrintExample(TextDocuments.java:378)
    at TextDocuments.runDemo(TextDocuments.java:152)
    at TextDocuments.main(TextDocuments.java:142)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.star.comp.loader.JavaLoader
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 6 more
```

Always a NoClassDefFoundError on bootstrap.. Searching for this but can't find much.. Anybody has an idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my LibreOffice installation the missing class is located in the file **jurt.jar**

Comment: Worked ty! now going further debugging